# Duplicate a tables structure

Tags: sql, sql-server, localdb

Ive got a localDB in VS2013, and I need to copy/clone the structure of a table and make a duplicate of it. How do I do this?

My Google skills are failing me.

P.s. The existing table is called manufaturers and I want the cloned version to be called manufacPt2.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you simply trying to clone the table?

Comment: Please provide data table structure.

Comment: @Brandon Yes. Thats all.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted, so downvoting doesn't really serve anyone's interest. If the downvoter actually took the time to explain WHY it was downvoted, I'd happily do my best to rectify the evil wrong that they perceive me to have committed. Thanks.

Comment: @WillMarcouiller I simply want to copy / clone the structure of an existing table and make a new table replicating the existing one but without the data that the first one contains.

Comment: @PhillHealey - I up voted to counteract the phantom down voter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to duplicate/clone the table.

```
select * into DestinationTable
    from SourceTable
    where 1 = 2
```

From this website: [**`Copy a table into new table with/without data - SQL Server`**](http://geekswithblogs.net/nagendraprasad/archive/2009/03/20/copy-a-table-into-new-table-with-and-without-data.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. I knew it was simple but just couldn't find anything. I appreciate the help.